# Pymongo ConfigurationError, server incompatibility

Tags: python, mongodb

When inserting into MongoDB, I get the following error message:

> pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: Server at xxxx:xx reports wire version 5, but this version of PyMongo requires at least 6 (MongoDB 3.6).

It seems like pymongo is not compatible with MongoDB. Since i can't update MongoDB, the only solution is to downgrade pymongo. But what version should I use?

pymongo installed 4.0.1

db.version()
'3.4.20'

Answer (score 2):

pymongo driver 3.4 to 3.13 supports mongodb server 3.4.20 , for pymongo 4.0.1 you need to upgrade the mongoDB server to at least to v3.6

Check the compatibility matrix [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/pymongo/)

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I needed, downgrading pymongo solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and as per [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/pymongo/) PyMongo supports MongoDB 3.6, 4.0, 4.2, 4.4, and 5.0.
My project has the following versions which work seamlessly-
pymongo==3.12.1
MongoDB==v5.0.5